# Global view variables in Kohana

Tags: php, view, kohana

I'm trying to figure out how to use global View variables in Kohana properly. I have a `Controller_Base` class which provides a basic layout of a page:

```
abstract class Controller_Base extends Controller_Template {

  public $template = 'base';

  public function before () {
    parent::before();
    View::set_global('title' , '');
  }
}
```

My `base.php` view looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And I also have a `Controller_Welcome` class inheriting from `Controller_Base`:

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Base {

  public function action_index () {
    $this->template->content = View::factory('welcome');
  }
}
```

`welcome.php` view looks like this:

```
<?php $title = 'Some title'; ?>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

The question is: how can I modify that global `$title` variable from `welcome.php` so in the end of the view chain `base.php` could get it? I don't want to put anything related to views into a controller.

Comment: "I don't want to put anything related to views into a controller." But the controller is responsible for providing the View(s) with the data it needs. Maybe you like the way Kostache works.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right. But I think that "everything that happens in view, stays in view" :-)
I know about Kostache, but want to know, if there's a native solution for that.

Comment: I think you have to write your own template Controller for that to work. This way you can manage the order of which templates are being rendered and when variables are being set and used.

Comment: Check out [`bind_global()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/View#bind_global). It makes sense to me that the template (base.php) view is rendered at the end, as first, all template variables must be set which can only happen during the execution and rendering of all the views and variables it contains.

Comment: @AmazingDreams I know about `bind_global()`. It puts a reference to some variable (or class property) to `View::$_global_data`. This means that I should a variable or a class property to store it. And I will also need to access it from the view somehow.

Comment: You are correct, these variables are included to the view as any other variable that would be passed to the view [see here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/View#capture). So `$view->bind('some_var_name', $var)` behaves the same as `View::bind_global('some_var_name', $var)`. In both cases it will be accessible by `$some_var_name` -> I recommend passing it as something like `$GLOBAL_TITLE` so you don't accidentally overwrite it. This way `"everything that happens in view, stays in a view"` is false.

Comment: That being said, what I always do is set a `protected $_title = 'Default Title';` and change that property either as a class default or in a method. Then in the `Controller_Base::after()` I pass that variable to my template view.

Comment: @rodweb Kostache *is* the native solution.  Despite not being an official part of the framework, several of the Kohana developers recommend using it for any significant template work because the built-in templates just can't do so many things (or require really ugly workarounds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

`welcome.php` view:

```
<?php View::set_global('title', 'Some title'); ?>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

`Controller_Welcome` class:

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Base {

    public function action_index () {
        $this->template->content = View::factory('welcome')->render();
    }
}
```

Note the call to `render()` - it is **very important** in order for this to work!  In the normal execution flow, the `base` view will be evaluated first, followed by the inside.  In order for the call to `set_global` to be made *before* the base is rendered, you must explicitly render the inside first.

---

**Aside:** If you are doing any significant templating stuff, you really should consider using Kostache with proper "ViewModel" classes, which are a much more elegant way to solve this problem.